# ASPNET Core 2.1 WebAPI selfhost with SSL

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, self-hosting

Using VS2019

Under development mode. Why must I first listen to port 5001, and 5000 before it is **redirected** to 44340?

```
WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder()
.UseSetting("sslPort", "44340")
.UseSetting("Urls", "https://localhost:5001;http://localhost:5000")
.UseStartup<CWebAPI>();
```

If I change 5001 to 44340, this is the error message that I get.

```
'Failed to bind to address https://localhost:44340.'
```

Why can't I just change the port 5001 to 44340?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix the issue by editing Properties\launchSettings.json to modify the applicationUrl in your app config.

Comment: I am having the same problem. There is no difference between configuration using code / json file.